# php.ini max_upload_file size falling back to default 2M

Tags: php, mysql, apache, drupal, drupal-7

I have to upload 5.7MB database in drupal-7 using module "backup and migrate". But, when I upload the file it throws out following error:

```
The file email839805758.zip could not be saved, because it exceeds 2 MB, the maximum allowed size for uploads.
```

I have changed `post_max_size = 20M` and u`pload_max_filesize = 40M` in php.ini file and created `user.ini` in /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/user.ini. and pasted post_max_size and `upload_max_filesize` greater than 2M. I have checked phpinfo(). It just gives the default value to 2M. Does anybody have any solution to such kind of scenerio in drupal 7?

I have found some additional stuff in drupal `backup_migrate.module` file which might be the barrier. Help me crack this function.

```
  /**
  * A custom version of format size which treats 1GB as 1000 MB rather than 1024 MB
  * This is a more standard and expected version for storage (as opposed to memory).
  */
  function backup_migrate_format_size($size, $langcode = LANGUAGE_NONE)    {
  $precision = 2;
  $multiply = pow(10, $precision);

  if ($size == 0) {
  return t('0 bytes', array(), array('langcode' => $langcode));
   }
  if ($size < 1024) {
  return format_plural($size, '1 byte', '@count bytes', array(),   array('langcode' => $langcode));
  }
  else {
  $size = ceil($size * $multiply / 1024);
  $string = '@size KB';
  if ($size >= (1024 * $multiply)) {
  $size = ceil($size / 1024);
  $string = '@size MB';
  }
  if ($size >= 1000 * $multiply) {
  $size = ceil($size / 1000);
  $string = '@size GB';
  }
  if ($size >= 1000 * $multiply) {
  $size = ceil($size / 1000);
  $string = '@size TB';
  }
   return t($string, array('@size' => round($size/$multiply, $precision)), array('langcode' => $langcode));
  }

  }
```

Comment: Maybe it sets in code by `ini_set()`? Find this place or add `ini_set('post_max_size', '20M')` in handler of your form.

Comment: where is ini_set() i can't find it in php.ini

Comment: see it in code of your application, CTRL + Shitf + F if you use PhpStorm

Comment: Second variant are more prefer because you don't need upload file with this size at all your forms

Comment: Search for post_max_size on php.ini and increase it to your desired size.Don't forget to restart your server

Comment: i have added one additional function from drupal backup_migrate.module file. Help me with that. I think there is problem

Answer (score 1):

Put in phpinfo() in your script and see which php.ini file you are using. Go into that file and change those values. Please keep in mind the daemon has to be restarted (php-fpm or apache) in order for the changes to be activated.

If you can not do that for some reason, you can always use the ini_set() function locally while this is highly discouraged!

Answer (score 0):

Check with phpinfo() what php config file was used. To me it looks like you edited wrong php.ini. Also, don't forget to restart your web server (Apache?).